# JMail.AddURLAttachment dynamically generated file

Tags: asp-classic, jmail

I'm trying to solve, on paper a simple problem, but which just won't work:

```
jMail.AddURLAttachment "/downloadics.asp?confirm=" & objRS("GUID"), "Appointment.ics"
```

The script "downloadics.asp" generates an ICS calendar file based on a specific guid. The result is a downloadable file *.ics.

Everything else works - both the mailing part and the ICS script. Just not when trying to add as an attachment.

I have tried several variations but they all end up with an error, e.g.:

```
jmail.Message error '8000ffff' 

WSAGetLastError() returned 10061, Connection refused
```

I have had succes with adding an image from an url.

So, my question is: is it at all possible to attach a "generated" file like this or do I have to make it another way?

What could another way be?

Comment: Have you tried adding the full path rather than a relative one?

Comment: Actually I have tried adding the full path - but will try again just to make sure. I have seen other examples where someone used the physical path (using Server.MapPath) but I reckon that cannot be right here since I need the processed asp file...

Comment: I don't know jmail but If I were trying to do this with CDO then I would specify the physical location of the attachment on the drive.  And if the file had to be generated then I'd write a script which saved it to a specific folder then attached it from that folder.

Comment: Didn't work with full path - gave the following error: jmail.Message error '8000ffff' 

WSAGetLastError() returned 11001, Host not found

Comment: OK, John maybe you're right. But that would be a workaround because it involves more steps. And how can I change the script I already have to silently save the file to a physical folder?

Comment: Have tried several ways and the only one that works is the JMail.AddAttachment using a physical path. I have looked at the JMail.AddCustomAttachment "FILENAME", strText - and I think that'll do the trick. By putting the contents of the ICS file in the strText variable I can create a file on the fly. If that works I won't have to use a filesystem object to create a file, attach the file and delete the file. Will report back...

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I was able to solve the main problem.

The solution was to use:

```
JMail.AddCustomAttachment "FILENAME", strText
```

And just build strText with the contents of a typical .ics-file and giving FILENAME a name like something.ics.

My problem is now that the file is ANSI encoded and I need UTF8 without BOM.

Thanks all for pointing in the right direction...